# Multiple Capacitor plugins inside the same project

Tags: typescript, package.json, capacitor

How to define Capacitor plugin source for multiple plugins in the same project in the package.json?

I can define the source of one plugin like this for example:

```
"capacitor": {
    "ios": {
        "src": "./dist/plugin1/ios"
    },
    "android": {
        "src": "./dist/plugin1/android"
    }
}
```

But how can I define the source for plugin2, plugin3 etc? We have this inside one package since we distribute it as an SDK with various of plugins we want to implement